# Video streaming website without ability to download or stealing

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming

I have a few videos which I need to upload on any video streaming website like youtube or vimeo. But the problem with youtube or vimeo is that they can be downloaded illegally using browser extensions. Is there a streaming website that is free of illegal downloads ? If that's not possible is there a way I could use any free streaming software and use my own website to upload the videos ?

Answer (score 1):

Streaming is downloading. So no it is not possible. If you need to protect the content of the media, you need to apply DRM.